# Number of positive integers $\le n$ with different digits.

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

An integer $m$ is **acceptable** iff in it's decimal representation all digits are different. For example $9876543210$ is the largest acceptable integer. For each $n\in \Bbb N$, $\theta(n)$ is the number of all acceptable positive integers not greater than $n$.

Is there a simple formula for $\theta(n)$?

Comment: I know a formula exists for $n = 10^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Would this be sufficient for you? (I'm not sure if there is one for the general case.)

Comment: Yes, I encountered this question in a computer program. I think this special case simplifies the problem to some extent.

Comment: Something else that might help you is ignoring repeated digits if one digit is shown to be repeating. For example, after $3300$, there's no need to consider $3301, 3302, \ldots$.

Comment: This question is a special case of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/226821/6876

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a math answer, but if you're only interested in the results I guess my approach is much simpler to understand. I simply let the computer calculate the numbers.

## Simple Python solution

This one works, but is slow:

```
def isAcceptable(number):
    s = str(number)
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
            if s[i] == s[j]:
                return False
    return True

def getNumberOfAcceptableNumbers(n):
    acceptable = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if isAcceptable(i):
            acceptable += 1
        i += 1
    return acceptable

print(getNumberOfAcceptableNumbers(98765432))
```

It took over 5 minutes on my machine for 98765432. The result was 2,345,850.

I'm currently implementing this in Java. For 98765432 it takes only 32 seconds and I'm currently improving it.

## Java solution

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class DiffDigits {
    /**
     * All numbers that are not acceptable have at least one pair of two
     * indices that have the same digit. Take the pair where the lower 
     * index is maximal. Return the lower index.
     * 
     * @param number
     * @return -1 iff number is acceptable, otherwise index as described above
     */
    public static int getHighestIndexThatHasToChange(BigInteger number) {
        String s = number.toString();
        // i == 0 is the most significant digit
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Get the amount of positive integers that are acceptable in range [i, end]
     * 
     * @param i the first number to check
     * @param end the last one to check
     * @return
     */
    public static int getNumberOfAcceptableNumbers(BigInteger i, BigInteger end) {
        BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
        BigInteger ten = new BigInteger("10");
        int acceptable = 0;
        while (i.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
            int highestIndex = getHighestIndexThatHasToChange(i);
            if (highestIndex == -1) {
                acceptable++;
                i = i.add(one);
            } else {
                i = i.add(ten.pow(i.toString().length() - 1 - highestIndex));
            }
        }
        return acceptable;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(getNumberOfAcceptableNumbers(new BigInteger("1"),
                new BigInteger("9876543210")));
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Execution took " + duration / 1000000000.0
                + " seconds.");
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```

For $n = 9876543210$ there are 8,877,690 acceptable numbers. For this range, it took 56 seconds to execute. For every other range it will be less.

By the way, this sounds like a Project Euler task. Is it one? Which task is it?

Comment: thanks. but I may need to translate to Java solution to C#.

Answer (score 3):

Quite often, counting questions that are trivial for $n \le 10^d$ can be solved very efficiently in general by decomposing into decimal blocks of size $m\cdot 10^d$.

Define $\psi(n) = \theta(n-1)$ for convenience, and say you want to know $\psi(4537)$: decompose this into $$\psi(1000) + [\psi(4000)-\psi(1000)] + [\psi(4500)-\psi(4000)] + [\psi(4530)-\psi(4500) ] + [\psi(4537) - \psi(4530)].$$

Previous answers have already shown how to calculate $\psi(1000)$, but each of the remaining blocks is equally simple.  For instance, $[\psi(4500)-\psi(4000)]$ is just the number of acceptable numbers between $4000$ and $4499$, inclusive.  In this block the first digit is fixed, and the second digit is any of $0,1,2,3$ ($4$ being forbidden).  The third digit has $8$ choices, and the fourth digit has $7$, so $\psi(4500)-\psi(4000) = 4\cdot8\cdot 7$.

The other blocks follow a quite similar pattern, they can all be computed using nothing more than "count how many digits of $x$ are at most $y$" and testing for distinctness, all very efficient operations even for bases much, much larger than $10$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. [See this OEIS page](http://oeis.org/A073531) or [this MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Digit.html).

$$ \theta(10^n - 1) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{9 \cdot 9!}{(10 - k)!} $$

Comment: Not true for $n=0,1$ since $\theta(1) = 1$ and $\theta(10)=10$ (originally this comment overlooked the latter).  This is really a formula for $\theta(10^n - 1)$, but for all $n>1$ it makes no difference.

Comment: @ErickWong, thanks for the catch. (The summands are actually for the number of $n$ digit acceptable numbers.)

Comment: Indeed, this is why I always find it more natural (in a programming context) to work with the "$< n$" version of such functions rather than "$\le n$".

Answer (score 1):

- The first digit may be any of {1,2,...,9}, so 9 choices.
- The second digit may be any digit of {0,1,...,9}, except the first one. So 9 choices.
- The third digit may be any digit of {0,1,...,9}, except the first and the second one. So 8 choices.
- ...
- The tenth digit may be any digit of {0,1,...,9}, except the nine previous,. So 1 choice.
- It is not possible to have 11 distinct digits.

> So $θ(n)=9 \times 9 \times 8\times 7 ... \times (10-n) = 9 \times \frac 9! {(-n)!}$

Apart for the $θ(n)=0$ for $n>10$ already mentioned, you also have an exception for 0, $θ(0)=10$ since $0$ is acceptable.

Comment: Note all integers must be less then $n$. n is not the number of digits.